# Why does 3dd not work from the last line in vim?

Tags: vim

If I do `3dd` with the cursor at the next-to-last line in a file, two lines are deleted, as expected. If I do the same with the cursor at the last line, I'd expect one line to get deleted, but that does not happen. Why the discrepancy?

Starting file:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3 █
```

After `3dd`:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3 █
```

After `k3dd`:

```
line 1 █
```

Comment: hmm... this is interesting..

Comment: This indeed looks like a bug... please submit this to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).

Comment: this should be a bug. `:d3` works but `d2j` and `3dd` don't work.

Comment: [Reported on vim_dev](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/o_qDrrraYMk/az-lwzL3IAoJ).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say bug, since dd will delete that line ...

Edit: and yes, I can reproduce that behavior with any other number in front of dd as well ...

Edit2: except 1dd, this works as expected. To me that's a bug ...

My vim

```
    VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Apr  5 2012 10:17:30)
    Included patches: 1-411
    Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
    Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
    Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
    +arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
    -clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
    +cryptv +cscope +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs -dnd -ebcdic
    +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path
    +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand
    +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap
    +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm
    -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +multi_byte
    +multi_lang -mzscheme -netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra +perl +postscript
    +printer +profile +python +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind
    +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax
    +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse
    +textobjects +title -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual
    +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup
    -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
       system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
         user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
```